# 'locate' for case-insensitive words?

Tags: locate

I wonder how to use the command `locate` to search for words that are not case sensitive? Such as modify `locate normal` to search for results that have "Normal" and "normal".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That depends on the `locate` you use. There are a couple of implementations, with identical executable names, but various package names: *locate*, *slocate*, *mlocate*, *rlocate*.

Usually they all have `-i` and/or `--ignore-case` switch. Consult your `locate`'s man page for the exact syntax.

Also usually they have no configuration file, so if you want to set the case-insensitiveness persistently, set an alias in your .bashrc (or similar) file: `alias locate='locate -i'`.